# Ember Data JSON-RPC requests Example

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data, json-rpc

I would like to do Post requests to my zabbix server using EmberJS and ember-data

How would I go about querying with JSON-RPC ?

In python I'd do something like this:

```
HEADERS = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
URL = 'http://zabbix.mydomain.com/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php'
QHEAD = { "jsonrpc": "2.0"}

pl = QHEAD
pl['id'] = "8"
pl['method'] = "user.login"
pl["params"] = { "user": "ZabbAdmin001", "password": "NunYaBeez.001." }
r = requests.post(URL,headers=HEADERS,data=json.dumps(pl))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ember.js you can use [ember-ajax](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax), which is normally included in a new project.

Transforming your python code above to ember-ajax should look like the following (when used in a controller):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  get,
  Controller,
  inject: { service }
} = Ember;

export default Controller.extend({
  ajax: service(),
  actions: {
    sendRequest() {
      return get(this, 'ajax').request('http://zabbix.mydomain.com/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          "jsonrpc": "2.0",
          "id": 8,
          "method": "user.login",
          "params": { "user": "ZabbAdmin001", "password": "xxxxxxx" }
        }
      }).then(r => {
        // Now r is your response
        console.log(r);
      });
    }
  }
});
```